# NSTableCellView does not getting the first focus

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am literally trying to solve this particular problem. It's been a long time.

I have a Mac App, which entirely lives in the status bar. Whenever I open the app by clicking on the status bar icon, the popover opens the `contentViewController`. The `contentViewController` has a `tableView` and multiple `tableView` cells which are subclasses of `NSTableCellView`. A cell has a button which I hide and unhide using the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events in the `NSTableViewCell` subclass. And whenever I click in the cell it takes me to the web, as in it open a `URL` in the default web browser also closes the `popOver`. There is a `pointingHandCursor` which gets activated when the tracking event `mouseEntered` called. Also it will change to default `arrowCursor` when the tracking event `mouseExited` called in the `NSTableCellView` sub class

Okay. Whenever I open the app, it properly shows me the `pointingHandCursor` because the event got called and cursor got changed. Now I clicked on the cell, which opened the link in web browser and popOver got closed. Now opened the app again by clicking on the status bar icon. Now worst thing happened, I can mouse scroll around in tableView but at the same I could see that the cursor is not changing to pointingHandCursor.

I have tried calling `acceptFirstMouse` event and `becomeFirstResponder` everywhere. Everywhere as in, In subclass of `contentViewControllers` view, In subclass of `NSTableCellView`, In view window... Basically everywhere. And that didn't help me.

Also I have tried adding `global mouse monitor` and listened to `mouseMoved` event, on this event I tried to set `becomeFirstResponder` and `acceptFirstMouseMove` in `contentViewControllers` view, that didn't work.

Then I tried calling the same monitor again in sub class of `NSTableCellView` and did the same, that also didn't work.

Basically none of this given me the expected behavior. I want to achieve this.

Please help me out here. If you want an example on how this work. Follow this,

Download Product hunt App, open it, Click on any post, it will load the post in web browser, come back, open the app, scroll around, you can see the `pointingHandCursor`. But in my case after opening the URL the `pointing HandCursor` not coming. :(

Comment: Make it short, will you?  Only a few are willing to read every sentence you write.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a long standing bug with NSTrackingArea.
You must verify that the current mouse location is still valid.

use this:

```
NSPoint cursorPt = [self convertPoint:[[self window] mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream] fromView:NULL];
```

NOT this:

```
[self convertPointFromBase:[ev locationInWindow]];
```

I use code similar to the following in my mouse tracking UI.

```
- (void)resetCursorRects
{
    [self adjustTrackingArea];
}

- (void) adjustTrackingArea
{
    if ( trackingArea )
    {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        [trackingArea release];
    }

    // determine the tracking options
    NSTrackingAreaOptions trackingOptions = NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag | NSTrackingMouseMoved |
    NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
    //NSTrackingActiveInActiveApp | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow | NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder |
    NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingAssumeInside | NSTrackingInVisibleRect;
    NSRect theRect = [self visibleRect];
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]
                    initWithRect: theRect
                    options: trackingOptions
                    owner: self
                    userInfo: nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];

    //  DOESN'T work on any OS version up to 10.10 self addToolTipRect:r  owner:self userData:nil];

    [controller mouseMoved:[NSApp currentEvent]]; // tracking area changes imply mouseMoved in its scroll view (virtually)
    // IMHO a bug that apple doesn't call mouseMoved here.
}

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)evt { [controller mouseDown:evt]; }
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [controller mouseMoved:theEvent];
    if ( [theEvent type] == NSMouseMoved )
        [super mouseMoved:theEvent];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    // make sure current mouse cursor location remains under the mouse cursor
    NSPoint cursorPt = [self convertPoint:[[self window] mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream] fromView:NULL];

    // apple bug!!!
    //NSPoint cursorPt2 = [self convertPointFromBase:[ev locationInWindow]];
    //if ( cursorPt.x != cursorPt2.x )
    //   NSLog( @"hello old cursorPt" );
    NSRect r = [self frame];
    if ( cursorPt.x > NSMaxX( r ) || cursorPt.x < 0 )
    {
        [self mouseExited:theEvent];
        return;
    }

    [self mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent];
    [super mouseEntered:theEvent];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if ( controller.mouseHoverKey )
    {
        controller.mouseHoverKey = nil;
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    }
    //    if ( mouseHoverRow >= 0 && mouseHoverRow < [self numberOfRows] )
    //        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:[self rectOfRow:mouseHoverRow]];
    //    mouseHoverRow = mouseHoverColumn = -1;
    //if ( [[self delegate] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MouseHoverProtocol)] )
    //    [(id<MouseHoverProtocol>)[self delegate] resetMouseHoverInfo:self];
    //if ( [theEvent type] == NSMouseExited )
    //    [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
    [super mouseExited: theEvent];
}
```

Comment: will get back to you.